# Do Xcode8 support subversion 1.7 or 1.8?

Tags: xcode, svn

After Xcode8 Release，Xcode SVN Tool Require subversion 1.9 to work on it.
But even the lastest subversion client on mac do not support subversion 1.9.
Such as cornerStone.
Is there any way that xcode code support a lowwer version subversion?
Thanx Very Much!

Answer (score 0):

The subversion is integrated by XCode.
You can see it in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn*.

So you can use the system subversion 1.7 like copy override the svn* files.
And it will be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Svn is provided by Xcode, but in shim binary form:

https://macops.ca/developer-binaries-on-os-x-xcode-select-and-xcrun

This svn binary will appear to change version, depending on which Xcode you point it at.  Try it!  I took an Xcode 7.3.1 version of svn and moved it to an Xcode8 install, the version changed from 1.7.22 to 1.9.4, same binary.

I needed to lock down the version of svn to 1.7.22, and decided there's really two ways to do this:

1. Rebuild svn yourself.  There are a lot of options, and it will be hard to match what Apple is doing here.
2. Install a legacy version of Xcode 7.3.1, and write a wrapper script to fish out the older version of svn.  I did this with a bash script:

   #! /bin/bash

   # Install Xcode 7.3.1 to /Applications/LegacyTools/Xcode-7.3.1.app
   # Prefix PATH with /usr/local/bin
   # This script should be saved as /usr/local/bin/svn

   set +x
   set -e

   # Find old svn
   legacy_svn_cmd="env DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/LegacyTools/Xcode-7.3.1.app /usr/bin/xcrun --find svn"
   legacy_svn_exe=‵${legacy_svn_cmd}‵

   # Pass args to new command
   args=$@

   # Construct command
   cmd="${legacy_svn_exe} $args"

   # Execute command
   echo "Running cmd:"
   echo $cmd
   $cmd

This has worked really well so far, I see little or no performance problems.
You could also abstract this a little bit to run any command from the older version of Xcode, I have written a general command template and created a symlink /usr/local/bin/svn to solve the above problem, as well as enable any other command to run from Xcode 7.3.1, just create a symlink for it in /usr/local/bin.

Note:  This should only be used for simple commands that do not call back into Xcode, so you do not start mixing toolsets which could lead to trouble.  Svn is an atomic-enough command that I have not had any problems so far.